# Global variable change not reflecting in server call

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to call a server to check it's status. The server code has a global variable "status" which is set to either True or False. The server sends either 'UP' or 'DOWN' based on status value.

I am importing the server file into my main file and trying to set the variable to False. Then I send a new request and expect a 'DOWN' status.

myfile.py

```
import server

response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()  #1
server.print_status() #2 Prints True (the default value) as expected
server.status = False #3
server.print_status() #4 Prints False as expected
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()  #5
server.print_status() #6 Prints False as expected
```

server.py

```
status = True

def print_status()
    global status
    print status

class Handler(object):
    @staticmethod
    def handle(start_response):
        global status
        print status
        if status:
            start_response('200 OK')
            return ['UP']
        else:
            start_response('503 Service Unavailable')
            return ['DOWN']
```

Now I expect a 'DOWN' response at line #5,  but it's always returning 'UP'. I am printing the status value in server's request handler also. There the status is printed as True (line #5) instead of False, even though line #4 and #6 prints False.

There is no issue in server code, that I'm sure. It's probably because of the way I'm calling the server or using urllib2. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: some more code would be helpful, without it the answer to your question is down to guessing

Comment: @Nhor what part of code do think would be helpful?

Comment: ahem.. I guess the server process that replies to your http request is another process... maybe even running on another machine...

Comment: @Pynchia I'm running it on my local machine. And yeah I also feel there is some other process running. Can I make sure it doesn't happen and things get executed sequentially.

Comment: with `server.status = False` you're changing your instance (or class) attribute, while your `Handler` class seems to be behaving statically, so the first code snippet doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described in my comment and in Daniel's answer, the client and the server are two distinct processes, which do not share the `status` variable, even if defined in the same python module the two both import.

I would suggest to have the client specify the state via the HTTP call, POSTing it to the server

```
query_args = { 'status': 'DOWN' }
encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, encoded_args).read()
```

then the server can check the POST data and update its status accordingly (assuming the whole interaction makes any sense)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough information here to properly understand what's going wrong. But the server itself is almost certainly running in a completely separate process, to allow it to respond to requests. The internal variables in that process aren't shared in any way with the ones you get by importing the code in your shell; they can't be.

To make this work, you would need to actually communicate the value to the server process. The simplest way might be to write it to a file, and get the server to read that file regularly. Or you could achieve something similar with sockets.

Comment: I have added the server handler also. It's pretty simple one. Can I somehow make the instructions get executed in sequential order and not having to write on a file?

Comment: What does "sequential order" have to do with anything? You are changing a variable that is local to your console session. It cannot possibly affect what is running in your server process.